# GCM "upgraded" to FCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, parse-server

It seems to no longer be possible to enable the gcm api for new apps. If I'm using parse-server as a BaaS which requires gcm to push notifications out on Android side and I can no longer do that because fcm breaks that implementation. What now? I believe this is Google's way of pushing developers off of parse-server and into the arms of Firebase. Is it in fact possible to use fcm with parse-server or am I going to have to use a different push provider and implement parse-server's pushadapter?

Comment: [`parse-server` is open source](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server). Presumably, `parse-server` can be modified to support FCM.

Comment: This is true, however I need to migrate my parse hosted instance to Heroku as soon as possible, admittedly, I should have done it sooner. Now I can't because fcm is now required for new apps and also not currently compatible with parse-server. Push is important in my application so I need to keep it running.

Comment: Developing an adapter for FCM should be quite trivial given the amount of adapters already out there.

Comment: You can also use one signal, urban airship or any other adapter for processing your push and still have your data on parse-server

Comment: How would one go about developing an adapter for FCM? I know there is one for GCM and APNS. I've started my own however I doubt I'm doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending fcm message requires same setup for push as gcm on parse-server. Be sure to use serverApiKey and senderId from firebase console in settings. Also be sure to add

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:senderId" />
```

At the bottom of manifest and note that gcm_sender_id is the same as fcm senderId